# ngpgsl website doesn't shows any valid documentation link

Tags: github, npgsql

if you go to [npgsql web site](http://npgsql.projects.pgfoundry.org/)

then click on documentation Tab, you are then redirected to github npgsql page.

There (even if i signed in github), i only see :
source code ;
pulse ;
Issue ,

but no doc or wiki.
So, where are the official npgsql reference and getting started documents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is no longer the npgsql website, the new one is at http://www.npgsql.org.

I'll ask to have the old one taken down...

Comment: Thank you for your help. Redirecting to the new website should be a good idea as this old site is highly referenced on google :)

Comment: Yep, that's what we're going to do. Thanks.

Comment: Done, old site now does a 301 redirect to the new one